# How are the Project Tango depth, display, and device frames of reference related?

Tags: java, c, google-project-tango

I'm trying to find the relative transforms between `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH`, `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DISPLAY`, and `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE`. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/frames-of-reference) suggest that I can 
use `getPoseAtTime()` to find these transforms but I have been unable to get this to work. I just augmented the hello-tango-jni-example `onPoseAvailable()` callback in tango_handler.cc with this code:

```
static void onPoseAvailable(void*, const TangoPoseData* pose) {
  LOGI("Position: %f, %f, %f. Orientation: %f, %f, %f, %f",
       pose->translation[0], pose->translation[1], pose->translation[2],
       pose->orientation[0], pose->orientation[2], pose->orientation[3],
       pose->orientation[3]);

  TangoCoordinateFramePair depthPair;
  depthPair.base = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;
  depthPair.target = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH;

  TangoPoseData depthPose;
  TangoService_getPoseAtTime(0.0, depthPair, &depthPose);
  if (depthPose.status_code == TANGO_POSE_VALID) {
    LOGI("depth (%f, %f, %f) (%f, %f, %f, %f)",
         depthPose.translation[0], depthPose.translation[1], depthPose.translation[2],
         depthPose.orientation[0], depthPose.orientation[1], depthPose.orientation[2],
         depthPose.orientation[3]);
  }
  else
    LOGI("depth status %d", depthPose.status_code);
}
```

The table on the frames of reference doc indicates that this is a valid frame pair. When I run, however, I get this in the log:

```
05-09 15:30:58.418    9569-9786/com.google.tango.hellotangojni I/hello-tango-jni﹕ Position: 0.002639, 0.075693, 0.031650. Orientation: 0.569572, -0.040792, 0.820440, 0.820440
05-09 15:30:58.419   16639-9782/? W/tango-api-context﹕ Requested extrinsic parameter was not available: base: 40, target: 3
05-09 15:30:58.420    9569-9786/com.google.tango.hellotangojni W/tango_client_api﹕ TangoErrorType TangoService_getPoseAtTime(double, TangoCoordinateFramePair, TangoPoseData*): Failed to query a pose.
05-09 15:30:58.420    9569-9786/com.google.tango.hellotangojni I/hello-tango-jni﹕ depth status 1205139920
```

There are similar errors when I replace `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH` with `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU`, `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DISPLAY`, or `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR` (all of which the docs indicate should work). I do get valid output when I use a frame pair of (`TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE`, `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE`) so I know that initialization, configuration, and the calling sequence are working.

I tried to use a frame pair of (`TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE`, `TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH`) as a workaround but that returns a status of `TANGO_POSE_INVALID`. I also tried using the Java API but that crashes in the JNI glue to the C API.

Is there any way to get this to work? Does anyone happen to know the transforms that convert between these frames for the developer tablet?

Comment: As a quick walkaround, you could use TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR with TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_IMU. TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH and TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR are the same frame because they are the same sensor.